# Use .GLB / Blender files in Gridsome project (Vue.js)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, three.js, blender, gridsome

I use Three.js in a Gridsome projet, but I'm unable to import .glb file (3D model) with GLTFLoader. Gridsome considers img (png/jpg) or .js files stored in `src/assets` but not glb.

My files hierarchy :

[image]

My import function :

```
this.loader.load('../assets/models/mars.glb', function(gltf) {
  let scale = 5.6;
});
```

I receive a 404 error when loading the file.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [the /static directory](https://gridsome.org/docs/directory-structure/#the-static-directory) of Gridsome and rebuild your project All files in this directory will be copied directly to your dist during build.

After you can change your import function to :

```
this.loader.load('./nameOfYourModel.glb', function(gltf) {
  // Your code here 
});
```